# Computation time with respect to Dropout

Tags: neural-networks, dropout

I've been recently attempting to speed up neural network training (in PyTorch). My question is the following.

Does the computation time of a given feedforward neural network vary based on Dropout percentage?

So, does increasing Dropout decrease computation time?

Assuming we have a network:

$L_2 = \sigma(Drop(\textrm{ReLU}(X^{T} \cdot W +b))^{T} \cdot W + b_2)$,

does e.g., Dropout= 0.2 mean slower computation than Dropout=0.99?

Thus, is the multiplication sparse or remains dense and as such offers no speedups?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would depend on the exact implementation. While it's possible you could implement some sparse operations to speed up computation when the fraction of dropped out neurons is high, I doubt this is done in practice. Also dropout is a really computationally inexpensive layer (compared to say, a fully connected later), so you may be looking in the wrong area in terms of optimization.

Comment: I see. In fact, I was thinking of reducing the fully connected load via dropout this way, yet it seems this is practically not the case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @shimao's answer, the dropout is typically implemented via *masking with 0* which results in additional vector multiplications. It doesn't decrease the complexity, rather increase it slightly, without changing the order of magnitude. For example, it is implemented this way in [tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.14/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py#L4255). In PyTorch, I couldn't spot the exact location of the source code, however noting that TF doesn't implement sparse multiplication gives me a hint about how PyTorch would implement it since they're both quality libraries.